# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position

Tags: linux, centos

I use Centos 7 when I run code with python 3 I got this error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
> 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried to added locale throw this command `localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8` but I still have the same error

when type this command `locale`

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Try setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

Comment: from my search, I found that centos image does not have locale I tried to add locale but not run at the end

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by doing this steps

```
nano /etc/sysconfig/httpd
```

In this file add a following

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```